# Azure DevOps - One "aad user" type cannot delete DevOps work items

Tags: azure-devops

A new person in our company cannot delete work items in DevOps. Their "Type" is listed as "aad user" under Teams and they are included in all the right groups, just like everyone else in the company, but they do not have the Delete option on a work item. This is annoying. It doesn't matter which work type.

What can we check, double-check and check again to make sure they're set up correctly?

[image]

Comment: I apologise for the confusion - this is in Azure DevOps. I thought I was posting straight to an Azure DevOps community, or that those tags would automagically be added because I had clicked on a Support link from Azure DevOps. I now added the tag explicitly and also added it to the title.

Comment: Hi, I just got in to work and worked through my emails, so I haven't had a chance to let the user know that I changed their access level yet. I'll let you know.

Comment: It worked. I accepted your answer. Maybe next time, give a girl a chance to try out the advice first ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the new users couldn't see the delete option, you could check the following points:

- You could check if the users have the **Basic** Access level in **Organization Settings -> Users** .

[image]

**Note:** The **Stakeholder** Access level will have no access to delete work items

- You need to check if the users are in the **Contributors Group** in **Project Settings -> Permissions**
- To delete work items, you need to check if the users have the **Delete and restore work items** project-level permission in **Project Settings -> Permissions**.

[image]

For more detailed information, you could refer to this doc: [Remove, delete, or restore work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items?view=azure-devops#prerequisites).